# Fail to resolve docker compose service name from front end

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

Hi I'm new to using docker for development. I'm trying to communicate from frontend (react) to the backend (express.js) here.

I have enabled cors as well, I'm getting an error saying `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` when trying to fetch from the back end using the url `http://backend:4001`,

but it's working when I use the docker internal IPAddress, like: `http://172.18.0.3:4001`.

Following is my docker-compose.yml file.

Please advise on getting this working, thanks.

```
version: "3"

services:

  backend:
    build: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/api
    ports:
      - 6002:4001
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mongo:4.0.15-xenial
    ports:
      - 27018:27017


  frontend:
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 6001:3000
    links:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Comment: Also see ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will not work, because your browser(internet client) is not part of docker stack network, you have to configure you frontend service to connect to `http://localhost:6002` instead of `http://backend:4001`

Comment: I've got a question. This is not kind of unsafe? I mean by exposing the port on localhost instead of communicating the containers between them

Comment: @nivalderramas, sure thing but for some services like frontend apps and API endpoints their ports should be published and exposed to the internet. services that communicate only internally are for sure shouldn't be exposed (e.g databases services).